# Compute $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left[\ln\left(\frac{1}{0!}+\frac{1}{1!}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n!}\right)\right]^n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Compute
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left[\ln\left(\frac{1}{0!}+\frac{1}{1!}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n!}\right)\right]^n$$
If you have some nice proofs and you're willing to share them, then I thank you and you definitely  have my upvote!

Comment: There is a routine proof, the missing tail of the sum is $\lt \frac{1}{nn!}$.

Comment: *more proofs*... More than what?

Comment: @did: I'll be glad even if MSE users offer me one proof. I'm usually interested in many proofs for each problem. The beauty of math is to watch/tackle a problem from many points of view.

Comment: @MaisamHedyelloo: yeah, right. Thanks! We get the case $1^{\infty}$.

Comment: Why one would want to gather proofs of THIS statement is a bit mysterious to me. The limit is 1, quite crude estimates yield it, and the result is not especially interesting nor meaningful nor esthetically pleasing. But maybe I am missing something?

Comment: @did: for instance, this problem was given at a local math contest (high school), and our teachers usually give very nice problems in a math contest. In the end it's a matter of taste, and your missing point (imo) is that people think differently. (if you consider my comment is rude I may delete it)

Comment: Not rude, I mentioned my puzzlement and you presented some explanations, this is only logical. And, as I more or less explicitely already said, I would be at a loss to imagine reasons why your teachers (or anybody else) would rate this as *a very nice problem*.

Comment: @did: I see your point. Look, it's hard to find a way without making use of the missing tail. So, in high school many kids miss the point with the tail,and major part of them only remember that $e=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{1}{0!}+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n!}\right)$.

Comment: @did: but they also learn that $e=\frac{1}{0!}+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n!}+\frac{\theta}{n! \cdot n}, \forall n\ge1, \theta\in(0,1)$. Unfortunately this is often forgotten. The official solution makes use of this last $e$ representation.

Comment: Then ask for the limit of the same log to the power $(n\cdot n!)$...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One could check that
$$
\log\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!}\right)=1+\alpha_n
$$
where
$$
\alpha_n=\log\left(1-e^{-1}\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{1}{k!}\right)
$$
Note that
$$
0\leq\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n\alpha_n=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n(-e^{-1})\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{1}{k!}\leq\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n\frac{-1}{enn!}=0
$$
So
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\log^n\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!}\right)=
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\left(1+\alpha_n\right)^{\frac{1}{\alpha_n}}\right)^{n\alpha_n}=e^0=1
$$

Answer (score 6):

The obvious way is to bound the missing tail of the series. That tail is less than a geometric series with sum $\frac{1}{nn!}$.

It follows that the thing $w$ inside the logarithm satisfies
$$e-\frac{1}{nn!}\lt w\lt e.$$
Thus 
$$1+\log\left(1-\frac{1}{enn!}\right) \lt \log w \lt 1.$$
By the Taylor series for the logarithm, we have
$$\log\left(1-\frac{1}{enn!}\right)=-\frac{1}{enn!}+o(1/nn!).$$
In particular, for large $n$, the logarithm is $\gt -\frac{2}{enn!}$. 
Now dealing with the $n$-th power is easy. The limit is $1$. There is an enormous amount of slack. A tail that is $O(1/n^2)$ would have been plenty good enough.

Comment: thanks for both hint and answer! (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Let $$u_n = \frac{1}{0!}+\frac{1}{1!}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n!}.$$ The problem becomes to evaluating $$\ell := \lim_{n \to \infty} (\log u_n)^n$$ But since $$e - \frac {1} {n n!} < u_n < e,$$ we have $$1 - \frac {1} {e n n!} - \frac {1} {(e n n!)^2} + O \left(\frac {1} {(e n n!)^3}\right) < \log u_n < 1.$$ This gives us $$\ell = 1.$$